# QuickBlox: error !! Not able to run app in device after framework update

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, linker-errors, quickblox

Yesterday I updated the quickBlox frame work, since then I am not able to run the application in device, the app is running fine on simulator. its give me bellow error when I try to run in device.

any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update Xcode to latest 6.3 - this should work